# Use nth_element to get k-th point(by x-coordinates), but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to reorder the vector to get k-th point(by x-coordinates) in a vector.

Before k-th element, there are k-1 elements(unsorted) the x value is smaller 
than k-th's.

After k-th element, there are n-k elements(unsorted) the x value is bigger than k-th's.(n is the number of total elements)

I use nth_element to do this, but the output still same.
Can anyone tell me why?

for some reason , I don't want to use sort.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

class point{
    public:
        int x, y;
};

bool pCmpX(point a, point b){   //compare points with x-coordinate
    return a.x<b.x;
}

void outPoint(point a){
    cout << "(" << a.x << "," << a.y << ")";
    return;
}

void getMed(vector<point> p){
    nth_element(p.begin(), p.begin()+4, p.end(), pCmpX);
    return;
}

int main(){
    vector<point> set;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        point a;
        a.x = i;
        a.y = i;
        set.push_back(a);
    }

    random_shuffle (set.begin(), set.end());        //make point arrange random

    for(vector<point>::iterator pItr=set.begin(); pItr!=set.end(); pItr++){
        outPoint(*pItr);        //print vector before using nth_element
    }
    cout << " \n";

    getMed(set);

    for(vector<point>::iterator pItr=set.begin(); pItr!=set.end(); pItr++){
        outPoint(*pItr);        //print vector after using nth_element
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_ isn't a useful problem description. Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem, and describe the problem properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass vector with points by value to the `getMed` function. As a result, you find the nth element in `getMed`'s local copy of the vector. You should pass it by reference

```
 void getMed(vector<point>& p){
```